# DecisionTreeRegressor score not calculated

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, decision-tree

I'm trying to calculate the score of a DecisionTreeRegressor with the following code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree

# some features are better using LabelEncoder like HouseStyle but the chance that they will affect
# the target LotFrontage are small so we just use HotEncoder and drop unwanted columns later
encoded_df = pd.get_dummies(train_df, prefix_sep="_", columns=['MSZoning', 'Street', 'Alley',
                                                       'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities',
                                                       'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood',
                                                       'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle'])
encoded_df = encoded_df[['LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'LotShape_IR1', 'LotShape_IR2', 'LotShape_IR3',
           'LotConfig_Corner', 'LotConfig_CulDSac', 'LotConfig_FR2', 'LotConfig_FR3', 'LotConfig_Inside']]

# imputate LotFrontage with the mean value (we saw low outliers ratio so we gonna use the mean value)
encoded_df['LotFrontage'].fillna(encoded_df['LotFrontage'].mean(), inplace=True)
X = encoded_df.drop('LotFrontage', axis=1)
y = encoded_df['LotFrontage'].astype('int32')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
classifier = DecisionTreeRegressor()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_test = y_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)
classifier.score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy is: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100)
```

when it's gets to calculating the score of the model I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 9 and input n_features is 1
```

Not sure as to why it happens because according [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.score) the Test Samples are to be in the shape of `(n_samples, n_features)`
and `y_test` is indeed in this shape:

```
y_test.shape # (365, 1)
```

and the True labels should be in the shape of `(n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)` and `y_pred` is indeed in this shape:

```
y_pred.shape # (365,)
```

The dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of the score function shouldn't be the target value of the test set, it should be the input value of the test set, so you should do

```
classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
```